# Formatting bootstrap datepicker inside thymeleaf page

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having issues setting the date format in a thymeleaf page. I have included the html code below.

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date"></input>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code is below here

```
<script>
$('#date').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-M-yyyy'
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? I can get the datepicker to work properly its just formatting the date incorrectly. The date gets formatted as 04/13/2016.

Comment: If you try the [*online demo*](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox), that should work and produce  a value like "20-Apr-2016".

Comment: It should but unfortunately it isn't working on my end. Any suggestions on debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did mistake on date formatter

Please try as per my suggestion

```
$('#date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' })
```

Hope you will fix your problem.

Comment: No it just defaults to the wrong format - 04/13/2016

Comment: Please check this link [DateFormatter Online](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

Comment: @Albert may be you have catch problem with browser, clean browser history and try to access as per my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy"
    });
```

pls try check js on client by F12 -> network tab -> and review js file source code.